# Generating six random cards with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get six random cards from a deck of 52 to appear using Math.random() in javascript. Thus far, none of my images are showing up. All my css3 and javascript is embedded in my html5 code. Also, all my images are gif images. You may notice in the html5 code that die1 is blank.gif while evrything else is blank.png. My set image function should alter the src, so I would think that this should not matter. My code is as follows, thank you for any assistance:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title>Card Trick</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .table{
        position:relative;
        top:50px;
        left:50px;
        width:1700px;
        height:800px;
        background-color:crimson;
    }
    .key{
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:50px;
  }
    .startButton{
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:black;
        color:white;
    }
    .card{
        position:absolute;
        top:250px;
        left:250px;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var card1Image;
    var card2Image;
    var card3Image;
    var card4Image;
    var card5Image;
    var card6Image;

    function start(){
        var button = document.getElementById("startButton");
        button.addEventListener("click", pickCards, false);
        card1Image = document.getElementById("card1");
        card2Image = document.getElementById("card2");
        card3Image = document.getElementById("card3");
        card4Image = document.getElementById("card4");
        card5Image = document.getElementById("card5");
        card6Image = document.getElementById("card6");
    }
    function pickCards(){
        setImage(card1Image);
        setImage(card2Image);
        setImage(card3Image);
        setImage(card4Image);
        setImage(card5Image);
        setImage(card6Image);
    }
    function setImage(cardImg){
        var cardValue = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 52);
        cardImg.setAttribute("src", "C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/cards/" + cardValue + ".gif");
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class = "table"></div>
<div class = "key">
    <form action = "#">
    <p><input type = "button" class = "startButton" value = "start"></p>
    </form>
</div>
<div class = "card">
<p><img id = "card1" src = "blank.gif">
   <img id = "card2" src = "blank.png">
   <img id = "card3" src = "blank.png">
   <img id = "card4" src = "blank.png">
   <img id = "card5" src = "blank.png">
   <img id = "card6" src = "blank.png"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One big problem I see with the code, is that there is nothing preventing duplicate cards... you need to make each number unique.

Comment: Your button doesn't need to be wrapped in a form tag either, since it is being handled by an event listener.

Comment: @Gary Hayes you are right, I overlooked that detail. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the *id* of your button to `startButton`. In your current code you are trying to get the button by *id*, but the button does not have an *id* but a *class* attribute with value `startButton`.

You may change the `class` attribute to the `id` attribute for your button to fix your problem:

```
<p><input id="startButton" type = "button" value = "start"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `file://` urls as you image sources when you want to access data from your harddrive.

`cardImg.setAttribute("src", "file://C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/cards/" + cardValue + ".gif");`

Or better setup a webstack like [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) and develop your application using it.

Comment: adding file:// didn't show the images. If I type the name of the image such as C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/cards/1.gif where I have blank.gif, the image shows. My problem is how to get a random image from the 52 I have in my cards folder so that card1 is random. Thank you for taking time to look at my question.

Comment: Well I misunderstood you question then, btw. remove the spaces between the equals sign in your attribute definition. `type = "button"` is invalid html and should be `type="button"`.